# Will RoS work over I2C , without serial? ie; arduino to arduino communication without a PC?

Tags: arduino, serial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will RoS work over I2C , without serial? ie; arduino to arduino communication without a PC?

I have seen examples and tutorials on how RoS can be used in arduino. But all of them explains
how to get an arduino communicate to a PC over serial protocol.

I am working on a robotic project where arduino to arduino communication is required. Will I be able to imlement
two ROS nodes based on I2C as underlying channel ?

Or any other ideas to get the same goal ?

---

Edit: Thanks William for the quick answer.
Eventhough, ROS Serial ( http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial )  examples are shown for communication from arduino to PC , I believe arduino to arduino serial will also work for ROSserial.

Any pointers how I can implement a new underlying protocol for ROS node to node communication.
There should be "downward"  interfaces for doing this.  Has any one tried this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221107/will-ros-work-over-i2c-,-without-serial?-ie;-arduino-to-arduino-communication-without-a-pc?/) by [Ajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25114/ajan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-11-18**:
Maybe using a raspberry Pi with ROS as master for both arduino boards?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-18**:
@Ajan: please don't post answers to post comments, or updates to your question. Please use the *edit* button/link for that. I've merged your update into your question.

**Comment by [Ajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25114/ajan/) on 2015-11-18**:
will do . Thanks @gvdhoorn

**Comment by [Ajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25114/ajan/) on 2015-11-19**:
@Mehdi Thanks for the suggestion to use the Raspberry pi. But I do not need one. Do not need that much processing in my robot. Arduinos can handle it. Communication among arduinos is going to be a challenge. I am planning to use I2C . But RoS do not support it. Wondering how to write my own support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, ROS uses TCP or UDP over IP to do communication and isn't suited for i2c or serial to serial communications. ROS Serial (http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial) provides communication between a microcontroller and a PC using serial. But as far as I know there is nothing like what you've described.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0